# Compile error when using a companion object of a case class as a type parameter

Tags: scala, spray

I'm create a number of json messages for spray in scala using case classes. For example:

```
  case class Foo(name: String, attrs: List[String])
  implicit val fooFormat = jsonFormat2(Foo)
  object Foo {
    case class Invalid(error: String)
  }
  case class Bar(name: String, kv: Map[String, String])
  implicit val barFormat = jsonFormat2(Bar)
```

In the above snippet, `barFormat` compiles, but `fooFormat` does not:

```
type mismatch; found : Foo.type required: (?, ?) => ? 
 Note: implicit value barFormat is not applicable here because it comes 
 after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type
```

I don't want to use `barFormat` in place of `fooFormat`, and I understand that a case class automatically generates a companion object, but I don't understand why there's a compiler error here, and the error message is difficult for me to decipher. Does anyone know what the problem is here and how to fix it, preferably without removing my `Foo` companion object?

Comment: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-801

Comment: At least give us the type of `jsonFormat2`.

Comment: @downvoter, please explain your downvote.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner, the type of `jsonFormat2` is fairly cryptic: `def jsonFormat2[P1, P2, T T)(implicit evidence$4: spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol.JF[P1],implicit 
 evidence$5: spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol.JF[P2],implicit evidence$6: ClassManifest[T]): 
 spray.json.RootJsonFormat[T]`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't recognize that was part of spray, I thought it was a method you wrote. Actually, its type is `def jsonFormat2[A :JF, B :JF, T <: Product :ClassManifest](construct: (A, B) => T): RootJsonFormat[T]` - you probably made a copy/paste mistake and removed the `construct`.

Comment: Is the "right" solution then to pass `apply` directly? I was just copying an example of serializing case classes when I wrote the initial format, and it did not include `apply`, though it works fine until you "override" the case class's companion object. I guess this obscures the passage of the `apply` method by simply providing the case class name. Is it bad practice to define a case class companion object?

Comment: @jonderry Faced this same problem. You might want to change the 'spray' tag to 'spray-json'. The two projects are related (same author), but spray.json is not part of spray, I think.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From your compile error, it looks like `jsonFormat2` expects a two-argument function. Do you mean to pass the constructors of `Foo` and `Bar` into it? If so, you should do `Foo.apply` and `Bar.apply`.

Comment: It's a nuisance agreed, but there's no better workaround right now.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. The `jsonFormat2`'s number is supposed to match the number of constructor parameters for the case class (which it does). See [here](https://github.com/spray/spray-json#providing-jsonformats-for-case-classes) for Spray.json sample. Did @jonderry get the problem solved?

Comment: @akauppi, what's the problem with this answer? I'm suggesting exactly what you answered below, using `Foo.apply`

Comment: Ah, you're right. Before knowing the right answer, I thought you meant passing both `Foo` and `Bar` (or `Foo.apply` and `Bar.apply`) to (maybe both) the constructors, since they're expecting two arguments. Your text is correct - it says "two argument function" (different thing). Maybe because it doesn't actually show the correct way, I failed to recognize the solution was indeed right. Maybe rephrase or add the code clip from my answer?

Comment: There actually exists `jsonFormat1` through `jsonFormat22`. It matches allowed constructor params for case classes. To make it more automatic, I think, would require macros.

Answer (score 4):

Case class companion objects will by default extend one of the function traits. `object Foo` would have extended `((String, List[String]) => Foo)` but when you manually defined it you didn't extend that trait. This is why you couldn't pass it to `jsonFormat2`, which was expecting a `(?, ?) => ?`. If you make the following change your code should compile:

```
object Foo extends ((String, List[String]) => Foo) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Spray.json [documentation](https://github.com/spray/spray-json#providing-jsonformats-for-case-classes) suggests an easier way than @wingedsubmariner's suggestion:

> If you explicitly declare the companion object for your case class the
>   notation above will stop working. You'll have to explicitly refer to
>   the companion object's `apply` method to fix this:

So the correction for the question becomes:

```
implicit val fooFormat = jsonFormat2(Foo.apply)
```

*Added: This is in fact what also @geoffliu suggests in his answer.*